# Search String from a variable using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to Search a String from a Variable.

I am dumping Azure Activity Logs in a variable and trying to find a specific line for that log. Here is my codes below.

```
$log=Get-AzLog -ResourceId "/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qcsqldw/databases/DatabaseName" -StartTime 2020-04-01T00:30 
$find=$log | Select-String  -Pattern 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/resume/action' 
Write-Output $find
```

I am trying to Search this Line "**Action    : Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/resume/action**" from the Log

While running the above script I did not got any output.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You want to find `/pause` yet your code shows you wanting to match `/resume`. Since `-pattern` uses regex matching, you don't need surrounding `*` characters because `*` is not a wildcard. The beginning `*` should throw an error since in regex `*` is a quantifier and there is nothing to quantify.

Comment: Hi  AdminOfThings, Thanks for your comments. I have made the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are searching the the **Authorization Action** property from your Azure Activity resource logs. If this is the case then you don't need to do any string searching, and simply reference the `Authorization.Action` property. [`Get-AzLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-3.7.0) will give you a `System.Object[]`, which can just be queried normally with [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) or [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7). You can find out this type information with `(Get-AzLog).GetType().FullName`.

You could run this query to get all your results with `Foreach-Object`:

```
Get-AzLog -ResourceId $id -StartTime 2020-04-01T00:30 | ForEach-Object {$_.Authorization.Action}
```

Which will give you the `Authorization.Action` property from all your logs that ran from the start time `2020-04-01T00:30`.

If you want to modify this query to search for a specific action, you can filter with `Where-Object`, then select `Authorization.Action` from the results:

```
(Get-AzLog -ResourceId $id -StartTime 2020-04-01T00:30 | Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/resume/action"}).Authorization.Action
```

Comment: Hi RoadRunner, this solution helps a lot. Now I am able to search the log file.

Comment: @Baxy I'm glad I could help :)